# Postgres and Mysql connection

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have the need to enter data that is stored in mysql and enter it in postgres, I am currently doing the migration using nodejs.

But I would like to know, if there is any way to create a kind of link between postgres and mysql so from postgres to be able to make a select to a table in mysql, without the need to create foreign tables as for example, as is done with mysql_fdw.

Is it possible to use dblink to do this?

For example, I have this script that to connect from one db in postgres to another to see its tables, but I only use it from postgres to postgres.

```
        SELECT table_name,table_schema
        FROM dblink('host=localhost dbname=db user=postgres password=password','
            SELECT table_name,table_schema 
            FROM information_schema.tables 
            WHERE table_schema <> ''information_schema'' AND table_schema not like ''pg%''') 
        as tb(table_name text, table_schema text)
```

Comment: You need a [foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html) to access MySQL from Postgres, e.g. [mysql_fdw](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw)

Comment: I don't know of a dblink for mysql.  Why would you want one?  Foreign tables are generally superior.